# Outbound SMTP redirect

Tags: 12.04, iptables

How would I go about redirecting all outbound email on port 25 of my server to port 25 on another server using iptables. I have tried a few rules already and none of them are working.

Would appreciate any help that you could provide.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are attempting to accomplish? i.e., use the second server as a relay? And the re-routing would be inside your network?

Comment: Am trying to make it so all outbound email goes through another server, for filtering

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - represent ip of your mail server
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - represent destination ip

Edit

Maybe is better to do post routing.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i ethX -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp -m tcp  -j DNAT --to-destination yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

ethX - is output interface
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - ip address of mail server
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - ip address of filter_server

When mail server want to send mail to another mail server we will cacht them on output and send to server first to filter them.